# html2canvas conflict on Enumerable of prototype.js

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs, html2canvas, enumerable

I have this error while trying to render the page

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.getChildren is not a function
at html2canvas.js:2014
at prototype.js:298
at prototype.js:266
at Array._each (prototype.js:473)
at Array.each (prototype.js:264)
at Array.collect (prototype.js:296)
at NodeParser.getChildren (html2canvas.js:2012)
at new NodeParser (html2canvas.js:1860)
at renderWindow (html2canvas.js:1018)
at html2canvas.js:1005
```

this is my code in rendering the page

```
 var runH2c = function(){
    try {
        /*option.testTop = scrollValueX;
        options.logging = true;
        options.onrendered = options.onrendered || function( canvas ) {


        };*/
         var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; 
window.html2canvas(body, {
    logging: true,
    type: 'view',
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
            $this.h2cCanvas = canvas;
            $this.h2cDone = true;

    }
})
    /*    window.html2canvas([ document.body ], options);*/



    } catch( e ) {
        $this.h2cDone = true;
        log("Error in html2canvas: " + e.message);
    }
};
```

this is the code on html2canvas that has an error

```
NodeParser.prototype.getChildren = function(parentContainer) {

return flatten([].filter.call(parentContainer.node.childNodes, renderableNode).map(function(node) {
    var container = [node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ? new TextContainer(node, parentContainer) : new NodeContainer(node, parentContainer)].filter(nonIgnoredElement);
    return node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && container.length && node.tagName !== "TEXTAREA" ? (container[0].isElementVisible() ? container.concat(this.getChildren(container[0])) : []) : container;
}, this));
```

};

the version of html2canvas is -   html2canvas 0.5.0-beta4
and the prototype is - Prototype JavaScript framework, version 1.5.0_rc0 *  (c) 2005 Sam Stephenson

please, I need help for my project. what should I do?

Comment: You also need to share the code that is generating the error. It's also useful to state what you have tried i.e. what debugging have you done or have you tried a work around.

Comment: there i updated it

Comment: Are you able to update Prototype to any of the newer versions? 1.5.0 is at least 10 years old, alot of that code epically clobbers native methods built in to current browsers - 1.7.1 (released Aug 2012) does alot more checking to see if methods exist before polyfilling them. I'm guessing that you are running into a problem where `filter()` or `map()` is being replaced with the old method which does not comply with ECMA standards.